# CAS default user and missing permission to Administrator Panel

Tags: spring, cas

I need create fake CAS server on localhost. I copy [this repo](https://github.com/apereo/cas-gradle-overlay-template) and I run this. But now I have problem with access to Administration panel or something like that on user: casuser and password: Mellon.

Is there any UI to manage CAS? How can I configure CAS to use this as localhost authentication server?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any UI to manage CAS?

There is a UI that would allow one to manage application registrations and policies with CAS, but as of this writing, there is no UI to manage the CAS configuration itself. The Spring Boot Admin project might be an option to research.

Today, CAS configuration more or less is a source-driven process where you configure modules via build.gradle file and relevant configuration via a cas.properties file. You'll need to edit these by hand to prep your deployment.